# Log the output of Expect command

Tags: logs, io-redirection, sftp, expect

I have made the below expect script and I need to log the output of that script.

```
SOURCE_FILE=`ls -l *.txt --time-style=+%D | grep ${DT} | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $NF}' `
if [ -n "${SOURCE_FILE}" ]
then
    cp -p ${SOURCE_FILE} ${T_FILES}
    /usr/bin/expect<<EOD

        set timeout 60
        spawn   sftp $ES_SFTP_USER@$ES_SFTP_HOST_NAME:$R_LOCATION
        expect "*?assword:"
        send "$password\r"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "put /opt/AppServer/ES_TEST/todays_report/*.txt\r"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "bye\r"
        expect EOD
    EOD
else
    echo "No Files to copy" >> ${LOGFILE}
fi
```

I need to log the output of expect command in `${LOGFILE}`. How can It be done?

I have tried adding the below things, it doesn't work. What could be done?

```
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD >> ${LOGFILE} 2>&1

set timeout 60
spawn   sftp $ES_SFTP_USER@$ES_SFTP_HOST_NAME:$R_LOCATION
expect "*?assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /opt/AppServer/ES_TEST/todays_report/*.txt\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect EOD
EOD
```

Comment: Use of backticks is deprecated use `$(…)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LOGFILE is out of scope, did you export it. See environment variables.

You need to export a variable to the environment, or pass it as an argument.

e.g.
Let us say your program is called `abc` then do:

```
LOGFILE=./logdir/logfile
export LOGFILE
./abc
```

or

```
LOGFILE=./logdir/logfile ./abc
```

Alternatively, pass as argument:

```
./abc "./logdir/logfile"
```

And have in program:

```
logfilename="$1"
```

Comment: YEah I have the LOGFILE value declared earlier in my script. I didnt add it in my question. `LOGFILE="/home/oracle/logs/"`  You want it to be exported rather than declaring it?

Comment: @sabarishjackson That logfile name ends in `/` so is a directory not a file.

Comment: Edit the question to show the smallest example that still exhibits the problem, but no smaller. Do not miss out impotent bits. Test your example to check that it still exhibits your problem (not a different one).

Comment: @meuh I gave it as a sample. I had the path to the file_name.txt

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned redirection is working fine now. I didn't add anything new.

```
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD > ${LOGFILE}

set timeout 60
spawn   sftp $ES_SFTP_USER@$ES_SFTP_HOST:$R_LOCATION
expect "*?assword:"
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /opt/AppServer/ES_billing_report/todays_report/*.txt\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
expect EOD
EOD
```